# scroll animation link to div

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

So i'm searching for a way to get a smooth scroll animation to a div after clicking on a link. I've tried some tutorials online but I couldn't get it to work. The link has the id "knop", and the div I want to scroll to has the id "over"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--gemaakt door Timo Vossen D01-->
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
  <meta name="author" content="Timo Vossen"/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="aston martin logo" class="logo"/>
    <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="vanquish logo" class="logo"/>
  </div>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="pijl">
      <a id="knop" href="#over"><img src="img/pijl.png" alt="pijl" id="pijlfoto"/></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="over">
  </div>
  <div id="specs">
    <div class="laag">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="peformance">
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="laag">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add jquery to your website try this.

```
$(function() {
  $('#knop').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

**UPDATE**

more specific code for your task

```
$(function() {

  $('#knop').click(function() {
      var offsetTop = $('#over').offset().top;

      if (offsetTop) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, 1000);

        return false;
      }
  });

});
```

P.S. Thanks @david-li for the hint

Comment: This seems like an overly complex solution to his problem. You don't need most of the sanitation since you know exactly what the target element is, and that the element does exist.

Comment: For instance, I think that this will work just fine as well as be more readable:
$('#knop').click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
  });